# 2nd order differential equation $ E = E_o e^{-α' z} e^{j(ωt - kz)}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Show that $ E = E_o e^{-α' z} e^{j(ωt - kz)}$ is a possible solution to:

$\frac{d^2 E}{dz^2} - E_o E_r μ_o \frac{d^2 E}{dt^2} = μ_o σ \frac{∂E}{∂t}  $

...

$ E = E_o e^{jωt - z(jk + α')}$

$\frac{d E}{dz} = -(jk + α') E_o e^{jωt - z(jk + α')}$

$\frac{d^2E}{dz^2} = (jk + α')^2 E_o e^{jωt - z(jk + α')} = (α'^2 + j2α'k - k^2) E_o e^{jωt - z(jk + α')}$

$\frac{∂E}{∂t} = jω E_o e^{jωt - z(jk + α')} $

How does jw replace the $(α'^2 + j2α'k - k^2)$ term?

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDv72.jpg) screenshot.

Comment: FYI, you can typeset greek letters in mathjax/TeX by typing a backslash before the name of the letter (for example, surrounding \alpha in dollar signs yields $\alpha$, \beta yields $\beta$; capitalizing the first letter gives capital greek letters like $\Pi$).

Comment: Are you supposed to find a value of $\alpha'$ for which the given solution holds?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 I'm not sure, given the solution and how steps go, how does the math check out at the asked part?